# How to extract a link inside in text on tweet with Python

Tags: python, url, text, twitter, tweepy

I need to extract the url than it's on tweet when someone mencion me.

[image about what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFgKr.png)

**Problem**: If the tweet has url on tweet it's impossible take the text, but if the tweet only have text, I can take the text.

Thats are the results with diferents librarys.

**Tweepy library**

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(apiKey, apiSecretKey)
auth.set_access_token(accesToken, secretToken)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit= True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify= True)
search_words = "@LoremIp03500003 -filter:retweets"
tweets =tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search_words, tweet_mode="extended").items(20)
users = [[tweet.full_text, tweet.id] for tweet in tweets]
users
```

[image output Tweepy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFgKr.png)

**Twython library**

```
results = t.search(q="LoremIp03500003 -filter:retweets", tweet_mode='extended')
all_tweets = results['statuses']
    for tweet in all_tweets:
      print(tweet ['full_text'])
```

[image output Twython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcQJC.png)

**Twitter library**

```
api = twitter.Api(apiKey,
                  apiSecretKey,
                  accesToken,
                  secretToken)
api.GetSearch(term="@LoremIp03500003")
```

[image output Twitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwMI4.png)

**Final goal**: I need to make a CSV with all mentions of my twitter account with: username(person than mencion me), id_user, text, url(if have one on text), id_tweet

Comment: why are you searching for a URL, if you want to know only if you mentioned there is a way to confirm it check their official document https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet

Comment: Hi Darkknight, first thanks for answer me. 
The question is than when I search ever tweet with "@LoremIp03500003" and extract only the text, it’ ok . I mean, I’m used the library Tweepy with attribute text and it’s work and I can extract the text. 
The problem come when the text have some url on tweet, that’s it’s a moment than simply the attribute text doesn’t work. I mean, I want all text (including the url), but simply don’t exist this register when I print.